# What's wrong with my weak cantaloupe plants?

Tags: melons

This plant is a few months old.  I'm in zone 10A.  Although the vines continue to spread, it has always looked sickly like this with curled up leaves.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If this is not a vertical picture, which I don't think it is, allow the melons to grow up a trellis.  This is will help in the natural growth of your melons.  Then make sure to water your melons on a regular basis, providing the soil enough water to stay moist.  You don't want to overwater the melon but your vines look rather dry.  So I would recommend you increase your water.

I'm not sure how far apart you grew your melons but typical space between melons should be about 36-42 inches apart.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it needs water. I noticed that the soil is quite dry as well. I would try to give it more water especially if the temperatures right now are higher than normal